# postgresql date comparison: error: operator does not exist: date > integer

Tags: postgresql

Can anyone help me with formatting the following postgreql requests another way?

```
SELECT count(o.product_id), p.title FROM orders o, products p WHERE 
p.product_id = o.product_id AND o.order_date > current_date - 7 
GROUP BY p.title;

SELECT sum(p.price) AS total, o.order_date from products p, orders o 
WHERE p.product_id = o.product_id AND o.order_date > current_date - 7 
GROUP BY order_date;
```

I have tested the requests in Postico and PGweb with my tables and both commands give the desired output, but when i put them into my code i get the following error.

```
error: operator does not exist: date > integer
```

Here is a copy of the table schemas

```
orders(id PRIMARY KEY, order_number INTEGER, product_id INTEGER, user_id INTEGER,
tracking_id VARCHAR(50), order_date DATE)

products(product_id PRIMARY KEY, title VARCHAR(200), description VARCHAR(2500),
price NUMERIC(7,2), img TEXT, brand VARCHAR(50), horsepower INTEGER, 
deck_size INTEGER, product_type VARCHAR(5))
```

The product_id in the orders table references product_id in products.

Here are screenshots of the tables for visualization:

[image: table definitions]

Comment: What language is your code, and can you include that code?

Comment: SELECT count(o.product_id), p.title FROM orders o, products p WHERE 
p.product_id = o.product_id AND o.order_date > current_date - interval '7 days'
GROUP BY p.title;  use this, may help you out.

Comment: Both those queries you give above work just fine with those table definitions (I inserted `int` before `PRIMARY KEY` to get the table definitions to work)

Comment: `o.order_date > current_date - 7` will work. Your query as shown works just fine, see here: http://rextester.com/VRO13048 I assume the error is somewhere else in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am surprised that your query was running anywhere.  If you want to subtract 7 days from a timestamp, you should be using:

```
current_date - INTERVAL '7 DAY'
```

So use this query:

```
SELECT
    p.title,
    COUNT(o.product_id)
FROM orders o
INNER JOIN products p
    ON p.product_id = o.product_id
WHERE 
    o.order_date > current_date - INTERVAL '7 DAY'
GROUP BY
    p.title;
```

Note: I replaced your implicit, old school join, with a modern explicit inner join.  This is the preferred way of writing a join currently.

Comment: That worked. Thanks a lot for the tips. I've been coding for 5 weeks, so its a grind!!

Comment: I definitely will. it wont let me for a few minutes. thanks for the swift response.

Comment: `current_date - 7` is not an error, it results in a `date`   but   `current_date - INTERVAL '7 DAY'` gets you a `timestamp`

Comment: @Jasen Feel free to edit my post if you want.  Not sure what else I should be saying here.

Comment: The problem is that the question has code that works perfectly (apart from the table definitions which are slightly incomplete). also the question is using date not timestamp.

Comment: You're right, that should work.  But `NOW() - 7` would fail; perhaps the OP was actually doing something other than what was posted.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen `now() - 7` fails because `now()` returns a `timestamp` not a `date()` and `timestamp - integer` is not allowed, only `date - integer`

Comment: I copied the requests verbatim. I typed out the table schemas, but I can post additional info if it would help any.

Comment: I'm loving the comment party here, everyone is invited now :-) ... I have to assume that whatever I wrote worked for the OP, and the original code was not working.  Maybe the question should be updated.

Comment: I'd be more than happy to update it if I knew what the proper question was :/ I just appreciate that my project works now...

Comment: Screenshots added of table schemas from DB tool. Just for reference. thanks again, and my apologies if the question wasn't formatted properly!!